# How to insert data with select query in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

How to insert data with select query sum? I tried. The result is affected success > Affected rows: 1. but row no add in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE Clases(Segment1_ID char(4), Segment1_Name varchar(75), CompanyID char(4), amount Float(53));

INSERT INTO Clases (Segment1_ID, Segment1_Name, CompanyID, amount)
select Segment1_ID, Segment1_Name, dataupload1h_companyid CompanyID, sum(case when Segment3_Formula = '+' then dataupload1d_amount else dataupload1d_amount * -1 end) Amount
from t_dataupload1_header
inner join t_dataupload1_detail
    on dataupload1h_id = dataupload1d_id
inner join M_Account
    on dataupload1d_accountid = Account_ID
    and dataupload1h_companyid = Account_CompanyID
inner join M_Segment4
    on Account_Segment4ID = Segment4_ID
    and dataupload1h_companyid = Segment4_CompanyID
inner join M_Segment3
    on Segment4_Segment3ID = Segment3_ID
    and dataupload1h_companyid = Segment3_CompanyID
inner join M_Segment2
    on Segment3_Segment2ID = Segment2_ID
    and dataupload1h_companyid = Segment2_CompanyID
inner join M_Segment1
    on Segment2_Segment1ID = Segment1_ID
    and dataupload1h_companyid = Segment1_CompanyID
where dataupload1h_companyid = '1000'
group by Segment1_ID, Segment1_Name, dataupload1h_companyid
order by Segment1_ID, Segment1_Name, dataupload1h_companyid;
```

Please help. Thank you

Comment: Does the SELECT statement return any row?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to commit the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

If the select is returning the desired results then check whether Auto-commit is turned on in PgAdmin(I suppose you are using this) Or put COMMIT; after the insert.